# Reading an Integer right after reading a Char?

Tags: c#, console-application

Well, this is embarrassing.

While developing a language to be translated into C#, I found a conflict when trying to read an integer after reading a Char.

```
char foo = (char) Console.Read();
int bar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Doesn't work, as the return '/r' gets read from the int.Parse, and not a whole new attempt at reading?

Is there any easy/obvious way around this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question and can you please give a description of what you want your desired output to be?

Comment: What input are you expecting, what input are you receiving, what ouput are you expecting, what output are you receiving?

Comment: Also, consider using `TryParse` when parsing user input to different types to prevent un-necersarry exceptions

Comment: This works just fine when I try it.  Do keep in mind that console input is line based if you don't use ReadKey().  In other words, the Read() call doesn't complete until you press the Enter key.  But ReadLine() certainly returns the rest, assuming there is any.  Describe your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put a `ReadLine` in the middle?

```
char foo = (char)Console.Read();
Console.ReadLine(); // empties input buffer
int bar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was needing. Sorry for the inconvenience/ poorly formulated question.

Comment: @user2428986 this will work if you will ALWAYS have a char and then a newline and then an int. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Add another `Console.ReadLine();` to consume the `\r\n`

```
char foo = (char) Console.Read();
Console.ReadLine();
int bar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```